# how to get value query string in javascript and put it into a textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a query string in javascript which looks like this : Default.aspx?7KCN0008-001 and when i try to insert 7KCN0008-001 into the textbox i get [object Object] how can i put the value inside the textbox here is what i have:

```
function test() {
    var urlParams;
    (window.onpopstate = function () {
        var match,
            pl = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl,"")); },
            query = window.location.search.substring(1);

        urlParams = {};
        while (match = search.exec(query))
            urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
 $('#txtStockCode').val(urlParams[decode(match[1])]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be barking up the wrong tree, but as you wrote in your question, if URL is something like `Default.aspx?7KCN0008-001`, you could get the string `7KCN0008-001` by this code.

```
 query = window.location.search.substring(1);
```

So I guss you could simply put this string into the textbox

```
$('#txtStockCode').val(query);
```

The document of `location.search` is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, if the query is  `7KCN0008-001 SAVSS0.85B 2180 916941-000%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20 917418-060`, I guess you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="t1">
<input type="text" id="t2">
<input type="text" id="t3">
<input type="text" id="t4">
<input type="text" id="t5">
<input type="text" id="t6">
```

Javascript:

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1); // "7KCN0008-001 SAVSS0.85B ...."
var decoded = decodeURI(query);
var ary = decoded.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' '); 
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) { 
  $("#t"+(i+1)).val(ary[i]);
}
```

**DEMO**
JSfidle is here:http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/pH4mB/2/

Hope this helps.

Comment: one more thing if i have URL like this: Default.aspx?7KCN0008-001 SAVSS0.85B 2180 916941-000%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20 917418-060,how can i put 7KCN0008-001,SAVSS0.85B,2180,916941-000,917418-060 on its own textboxes like 6 textboxes?

Comment: @billah77, okay. You mean there are six values separated by space? (It seems five values.)

Comment: my bad there are five values

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confuse about the data structure. You first define it to be an Object and then you say its an array.

```
urlParams = {};

urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
```

You need to find out the value of decode(match[1]) and use this in the .val method as its an array....

```
$('#txtStockCode').val(urlParams[decode(match[1])]);
```

Comment: Okay since am really confused how can i change the structure of the data

Comment: :-) No structure of the data - the data structure. Array vs Object